# SQL Find how many times the users changed gender in the database per month

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I´m looking in to my user database to see how often the users change gender, there are three possible genders in the database, Men, Women and Unknown.

To track the changes i have a table that creates a new row every time a user changes any userdata. I would like to use this to see how many "gender swaps" that is performed every month.

Below shows a table for user 123, note that there could have been other changes to the user that didn´t change the gender, so each row is not a gender change.

The closest i have gotten is the query below that finds if there where two different gender changes in one month. But that requires the user to have two rows with different gender witin a month which doesn´t cover all the situations. For example they could have been registred as M and then changed to W in July.

```
#Test Query
SELECT
  user_id ,
 CONCAT( 
  (CAST(EXTRACT(year
        FROM
          modified_date ) AS string)),
      ( CAST(EXTRACT(month
          FROM
            modified_date ) AS string)))AS yearmonth ,
            array_agg(gender order by modified desc limit 1)[safe_ordinal(1)] as agg_first,
            array_agg(gender order by modified asc limit 1)[safe_ordinal(1)] as agg_last
    FROM
      START_TABLE
    group by 1,2
```

```
#START_TABLE 
SELECT 123 as user_id, "MALE" as gender, "2019-06-03 14:53:13 UTC" as modified_date
UNION ALL
select 123,"MALE", "2019-06-09 14:53:13 UTC" 
UNION ALL
select 123,"FEMALE", "2019-06-14 14:53:13 UTC" 
union all
select 123, "MALE", "2019-07-03 14:53:13 UTC" 
UNION ALL
select 123,"MALE", "2019-07-09 14:53:13 UTC" 
UNION ALL
select 123,"MALE", "2019-07-21 14:53:13 UTC" 
union all
select 123,"MALE", "2019-08-01 14:53:13 UTC" 
union all
select 123,"MALE", "2019-08-02 14:53:13 UTC" 
union all
select 123, "UNKNOWN", "2019-09-03 14:53:13 UTC"
```

```
#RESULT_TABLE 
SELECT "2019-06" as yearmonth, 1 as m_to_w, 0 as m_to_u, 0 as w_to_m, 0 as w_to_u, 0 as u_to_m, 0 as u_to_w
UNION ALL
select "2019-07",0,0,1,0,0,0
UNION ALL
select "2019-09",0,1,0,0,0,0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT user_id, FORMAT_DATE('%Y-%m', DATE(modified_date)) yearmonth,  
  COUNTIF((prev_gender, gender) = ('MALE', 'FEMALE')) AS m_to_w,
  COUNTIF((prev_gender, gender) = ('MALE', 'UNKNOWN')) AS m_to_u,
  COUNTIF((prev_gender, gender) = ('FEMALE', 'MALE')) AS w_to_m,
  COUNTIF((prev_gender, gender) = ('FEMALE', 'UNKNOWN')) AS w_to_u,
  COUNTIF((prev_gender, gender) = ('UNKNOWN', 'MALE')) AS u_to_m,
  COUNTIF((prev_gender, gender) = ('UNKNOWN', 'FEMALE')) AS u_to_w
FROM (
  SELECT *, LAG(gender) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY modified_date) prev_gender
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
GROUP BY user_id, yearmonth
HAVING m_to_w + m_to_u + w_to_m + w_to_u + u_to_m + u_to_w > 0
-- ORDER BY user_id, yearmonth
```

If to apply to sample data from your question

```
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 123 AS user_id, 'MALE' AS gender, TIMESTAMP '2019-06-03 14:53:13 UTC' AS modified_date UNION ALL
  SELECT 123, 'MALE', '2019-06-09 14:53:13 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 123, 'FEMALE', '2019-06-14 14:53:13 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 123, 'MALE', '2019-07-03 14:53:13 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 123, 'MALE', '2019-07-09 14:53:13 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 123, 'MALE', '2019-07-21 14:53:13 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 123, 'MALE', '2019-08-01 14:53:13 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 123, 'MALE', '2019-08-02 14:53:13 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 123, 'UNKNOWN', '2019-09-03 14:53:13 UTC' 
)
```

result is

```
Row user_id yearmonth   m_to_w  m_to_u  w_to_m  w_to_u  u_to_m  u_to_w   
1   123     2019-06     1       0       0       0       0       0    
2   123     2019-07     0       0       1       0       0       0    
3   123     2019-09     0       1       0       0       0       0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `lag()` to find when users change gender:

```
select st.*
from (select st.*,
             lag(gender) over (partition by user order by modified date) as prev_gender
      from start_table st
     ) st
where prev_gender <> gender;
```

With this logic, you can summarize:

```
select date_trunc(modified_date, month) as yyyymm,
       count(*) as num_changes,
       count(distinct user) as num_users
from (select st.*,
             lag(gender) over (partition by user order by modified_date) as prev_gender
      from start_table st
     ) st
where prev_gender <> gender
group by yyyymm
order by yyyymm;
```

EDIT:

You want the specific changes as well.  You can use `COUNTIF()`:

```
select date_trunc(modified_date, month) as yyyymm,
       countif( prev_gender = 'MALE' and gender = 'FEMALE' ) as m_to_f,
       countif( prev_gender = 'MALE' and gender = 'UNKNOWN' ) as m_to_u,
       . . .
from (select st.*,
             lag(gender) over (partition by user order by modified_date) as prev_gender
      from start_table st
     ) st
group by yyyymm
order by yyyymm;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LAG` function to achieve this. Here is a version which uses `LAG` and `IF` function to take into account those discrete conditions:

```
with processed as (
   select 
      concat(
         cast(extract(year from modified_date) as string),
         '-', 
         cast(extract(month from modified_date) as string)
      ) as yearmonth,
      lower(gender) as gender,
      lower(lag(gender) over (partition by user_id order by modified_date)) as previous_gender
   from `mytable.dataset`
)

select 
   yearmonth, 
   sum(if (previous_gender = "male" and gender = "female", 1, 0) ) as m_to_f,
   sum(if (previous_gender = "male" and gender = "unknown", 1, 0) ) as m_to_u,
   sum(if (previous_gender = "female" and gender = "male", 1, 0) ) as f_to_m,
   sum(if (previous_gender = "female" and gender = "unknown", 1, 0) ) as f_to_u,
   sum(if (previous_gender = "unknown" and gender = "male", 1, 0) ) as u_to_m,
   sum(if (previous_gender = "unknown" and gender = "female", 1, 0) ) as u_to_f
from processed
group by 1
```

Hope it helps.